# MongoClient not found when put on server

Tags: php, mongodb

I have installed and successfully connected to MongoDB from my local machine. When I ran the site which uses it from my localhost it has no problem connecting to it, but when I upload the folder to a FTP client and connect to a web hosting and domain it says MongoClient class not found.

Should I change something in the config.php file? Now it looks like this:

```
<?php
    $conn = new MongoClient();
    $data = $conn->db; 
?>
```

Comment: Check if the MongoDB PHP Extension is installed and enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Install Mongodb Extension with:

```
apt-get install php-pear php5-dev
pecl install mongo
```

Comment: Yes,the php extension is installed and enabled, it connects fine to the database when I run the website from my local machine. But when i drag the folders to the ftp client (i'm using cyberduck) to upload the content on the web hosting it doesn't connect to the mongoDB. I'm thinking I should include in the www folder some mongodb folder (like the data and bin) as well, but it's still not working...

Comment: @Iva is it installed on the server?